# Direct BeginUmbracoForm action to another page

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I am trying to set up a global search box that posts to a search page in umbraco 7. This template uses a shared partial containing Html.BeginUmbracoForm() that points to a SurfaceController.

Since this is a global control, I want the form to be posted to the /search page instead of the current page. BeginUmbracoForm only seems to be able to post to the current page unless I'm mistaken.

I want something like RedirectToUmbracoPage(id), but clears this post values on redirect.

Is there a way to get an ActionResult like CurrentUmbracoPage which keeps the post values?

Answer (score 0):

I would not try using surfacecontrollers for that purpose.  [Surfacecontrollers](http://our.umbraco.org/Documentation/Reference/Mvc/surface-controllers) are auto routed.  They are created to (e.g.) make `@Html.Action(...)` work on every umbraco page.  Including postbacks on these actions or macros.

If you only need a "redirect" to the /search page, you don't need a surface controller.  A simple partial will do the job.

```
<form action="/search" method="get">
  Search <input type="search" name="q" />
</form>
```

Of course you can replace the url using some Umbraco logic like `@Umbraco.TypedContentSingleAtXPath("//Search")` or other Umbraco magic.

In the umbraco documentation project is an example where [Html.Action is used](http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/Templating/Mvc/child-actions).